# CPAN installing Net::Pcap and Packet module failed due to lpcap

Tags: perl, cpan, pcap

Recently, I tried to install perl module Net::Packet and Net::Pcap through cpan but it complained that it cannot find pcap library. So I was searching if cpan would accept external lib/include directory when installing module, but no luck til now.

```
looking for -lpcap... no
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
You appear to lack the pcap(3) library. 

If it is installed in a non-standard locatio n, please try setting the LIBS 
and INC values on the command line.

Or get the sources and install the pcap library from http://www.tcpdump.org/

If you install the pcap library using a system package, make sure to also 
install the corresponding -devel package, which contains the C headers needed 
to compile this module. 
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

my pcap library is located at /opt/local/lib and header at /opt/local/include/pcap.
Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting the LIBS and INC values on the command line?

Comment: was it something like "cpan module LIBS=path INC=path" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [README](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Pcap/README) file for [Net::Pcap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aPcap) shows how to tell Makefile.PL where to find the pcap library:

```
perl Makefile.PL INC=-I/opt/local/include/pcap LIBS='-L/opt/local/lib -lpcap'
```

(I've inserted your paths into the example.)

However, getting the [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cpan) shell to pass those arguments to Makefile.PL is rather more complicated.  You'd have to use the [Distroprefs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN#Configuration_for_individual_distributions_%28Distroprefs%29) system and create a YAML file to supply the arguments.  If you're not already familiar with Distroprefs, it'll probably be easier to just install Net::Pcap by hand.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed my issue:

```
yum -y install perl-Net-Pcap libpcap-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, just install libnet-pcap-perl.